# GSON malformed url exception

Tags: android, gson

I am converting json object to java object but i keep getting error
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 20 path $[0].urlToImage

Here is my code

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            JSONArray recArticles = new JSONArray();
            try {
                recArticles = response.getJSONArray("articles");
                for (int i=0;i<recArticles.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = recArticles.getJSONObject(i);;

                    String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String description = jsonObject.getString("description");
                    String url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                    String urlToImage = jsonObject.getString("urlToImage");
                    HashMap<String, String> singleArticle = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    singleArticle.put("author", author);
                    singleArticle.put("title", title);
                    singleArticle.put("description", description);
                    singleArticle.put("url", url);
                    singleArticle.put("urlToImage", urlToImage);
                    mArticleList.add(String.valueOf(singleArticle));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type articleListType = new TypeToken<Collection<RecArticle>>() {}.getType();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + mArticleList);
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + String.valueOf(mArticleList));
            mArticles = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(mArticleList), articleListType);
            mArticleAdapter = new RecommenderAdapter(getContext(), mArticles);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);

            mAviLib.hide();
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
```

Comment: Put your JSON please, the error says JSON is malformed.

Comment: here is the link https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=2743bc85885242bbade88d6c0a25c511

Comment: Gson.fromJson takes a json string. I guess mArticleList is not a json string.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json response seems to be correct.

But why you are parsing half of your with gson and other half of it manually? There is no logic at all.

Use it Like that:

**Article.java**

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Article {

@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
private String author;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
@Expose
private String urlToImage;
@SerializedName("publishedAt")
@Expose
private String publishedAt;

public String getAuthor() {
return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public String getUrlToImage() {
return urlToImage;
}

public void setUrlToImage(String urlToImage) {
this.urlToImage = urlToImage;
}

public String getPublishedAt() {
return publishedAt;
}

public void setPublishedAt(String publishedAt) {
this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
}

}
```

ResponseModel.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResponseModel {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("source")
@Expose
private String source;
@SerializedName("sortBy")
@Expose
private String sortBy;
@SerializedName("articles")
@Expose
private List<Article> articles = null;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getSource() {
return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
this.source = source;
}

public String getSortBy() {
return sortBy;
}

public void setSortBy(String sortBy) {
this.sortBy = sortBy;
}

public List<Article> getArticles() {
return articles;
}

public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
this.articles = articles;
}

}
```

And parse like this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ResponseModel responseModel = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ResponseModel.class);
            List<Article> articles = responseModel.getArticles();
            mArticleAdapter = new RecommenderAdapter(getContext(), articles);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);

            mAviLib.hide();
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
```